# Single error handler for promises

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the promise returned by jquery provide provision for handling all the errors in a single place at the end. Something like this:

[image]

If so I would appreciate some code, perhaps with raw `$.deferred` , `.done` and `.fail`

Tried documentation : http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: If you chain then calls, you can attach a handler at the end that catches rejects anywhere in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The answer assumes jQuery 1.8+. Prior to jQuery 1.8, jQuery's promise/deferred implementation did not work this way.

There is a subtle difference between `.done()` / `.fail()` and the `.then()` functions - as of 1.8, `.then()`'s main usage is to apply *filters*, while `.done()` / `.fail()` simply apply callbacks. The difference is that `.done()` and `.fail()` return the same promise(thus calling `.done().done().done()` simply adds more callbacks to your initial promise), while `.then()`returns a new promise for the value returned from your filters(so `.then(success)` returns a new promise which will be resolved with the value that success returns).

A demonstration of this difference can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/HsMSv/4/

So to replicate the same functionality as that image, you would need:

```
Deferred.then(success_a)
        .then(success_b)
        .then(success_c, failure);
```

Sadly, the jQuery documentation is a bit sketchy on the subject, but you can see it at http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Using `$.when()` as in the accepted answer will also work, since it will return a new promise which is rejected when *any* of the given promises are rejected, and is successfully resolved with the combined data from all of them.

Comment: Thanks sacho. Saved me a ton of time. An excellent answer with fiddle and all.

Comment: this is probably what you meant (def2 instead of def) : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/HsMSv/5/

Answer (score 2):

```
var jqXHR1 = $.get('/echo/json/'),
    jqXHR2 = $.get('/echo/json/');

$.when(jqXHR1, jqXHR2).then(function(data1, data2){

    //success, do stuff with the data objects

}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

    //error in at least one of the requets:
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

});
```

Try switching to an invalid url to end up in the error callback.

http://jsfiddle.net/VHjzM/

Comment: Agree with the answer, only a minor note - jQuery's `$.when()` is not the same as the `when()` in that pseudo-javascript - the pseudo-javascript has a definite sequence of execution(first my_promise, then success_a, then success_b...).

Comment: +1 for introducing me to when http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ But it goes inside whereas I would prefer if there was a syntax like (or perhaps its the default behaviour?) `xhr1.done(xhr2).fail(/*called when either xhr fails*/`

Comment: You can use those as well. `.done` and `.fail` are simply shortcuts for `.then(success, failure)`

Comment: @Sacho Thanks thats the answer I was looking for. The documentation mentions `When the Deferred is rejected, the failCallbacks are called. Callbacks are executed in the order they were added` But I was unclear if it would work that way. Would be happy to mark as answer if you post it.

Comment: Actually, my comments were wrong - I reviewed the documentation and came up with an appropriate answer.